# Warning: Please use \TABLE{...} in place of LaTeX environment

Tags: tables, templates, warnings

Please see the MWE:

```
\documentclass{JHEP}

\author{me}
\abstract{a}
\title{title}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
 hello
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

After compiling i got this warning:

> Warning: Please use \TABLE{...} in place of LaTeX environment

Why is that? What does this warning mean? Also getting similar warning with \figure enviroment

> Warning: Please use \FIGURE{...} in place of LaTeX environment

[JHEP avaliable here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/jhep)

Comment: Use `\TABLE{\begin{tabular}{c} ... \end{tabular}}` instead, the same holds true for `\FIGURE` instead of `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}`. It is a little bit unusual, in my point of view...

Comment: It does not really work, "hello" won't deisplayed, and \begin{center} gives error for \documentclass{JHEP}

\author{me}
\abstract{a}
\title{title}

\begin{document}

\TABLE{
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c}
 hello
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
}

\end{document}

Comment: Well, is "don't publish in JHEP" a valid answer"? _/sarcasm_

Comment: @tohecz: I did not say 'do not publish in JHEP';-)

Comment: @tohecz,@JosephWright: I found a link: http://jhep.sissa.it/jhep/help/helpLoader.jsp?pgType=author#file, with a download link to a (presumably) more up-to-date `*.sty` file named `jheppub.sty`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`jhep` is a somehow very strange class ;-)

Seriously spoken: I would not use this class if it is not really necessary, but, honestly, I can not provide an alternative however.

Perhaps unrelated, but [Change font size in JHEP class document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407172/change-font-size-in-jhep-class-document) shows that this class is really weird.

```
\documentclass{jhep}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\author{me}
\abstract{a}
\title{JHEP -- a very strange \LaTeX~ class}



\begin{document}
\blindtext
\TABLE{%
\begin{tabular}{llll}%
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \tabularnewline
1 & 4 & 9 & 16 \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}%
\caption{Some Table}
}%

\blindtext % Some dummy text, otherwise the table is not shipped out


\end{document}
```

**Notes**

- `jhep` seems to be up to date (if up to date means 2002/2003) ;-)
- Tables are somehow wrapped around
- Shipout of tables/figures seems to be only possible if there is any other
  content too.

[image]

**EDIT**

With `jheppub.sty` everything works as expected, please download it from http://jhep.sissa.it/jhep/help/JHEP_TeXclass.jsp

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{jheppub}
\author{me}
\abstract{a}
\title{JHEPPUB -- a better package}



\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{llll}%
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \tabularnewline
1 & 4 & 9 & 16 \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}%
\caption{Some Table}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Certainly odd: claims GPL license but 'name must change'!

Comment: @JosephWright: Do you think it would be useful to notice the 'maintainer'? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Unfortunately i must use JHEP. I think i can live with that warning.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps[the `environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) can be used to redefine the `table` environment:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `\fbox{}` was added to highlight the table in the output.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{class/JHEP}
\usepackage{environ}

\let\table\relax
\let\endtable\relax
\NewEnviron{table}{%
    \TABLE{\BODY}%
}%

\author{me}
\abstract{a}
\title{title}

\begin{document}
Some text before
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
 \fbox{hello}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
Some text after
\end{document}
```