# Using Tikz Package with JHEP3.cls

Tags: tikz-pgf, document-classes

I am using JHEP3.cls document class.

```
\documentclass[hyper,11pt]{JHEP3}

\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

Blah Blah Blah 

\end{document}
```

At some point of my document, I need to use the tikz package. However, I get the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
```

Also, the following:

```
Undefined control sequence. ...BLAH}{2}
```

When I click on the above log, I get:

```
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1} BLAH}{2}
```

Where BLAH is the name of the subsection or subsubsection (but not section, it seems that the section!). When I remove the tikz package from the preamble, I can compile the document and there is no problem. However, when I add it to the preamble, the document cannot be compiled. Also, it seems that tikz has not been included in the JHEP3.cls class. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Your question will get much more attention if you provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Are you using this one? https://jhep.sissa.it/jhep/help/JHEP_TeXclass.jsp

Comment: @MajidAbdolshah No, the one here https://jhep.sissa.it/jhep/help/JHEP/TeXclass/tools_JHEPlog.html
which seems to be obsolete, the last update goes back to 2016. The one that you mentioned works perfectly. I might need to use this one.

Comment: @marmot I updated my questions.

Comment: In my case, it complains that there are no author, title and abstract given. But after I provide them, I still get an error. I'm wondering if @MajidAbdolshah wants to write an answer.

Comment: Perhaps unrelated,but about the quality of the `JHEP` classes see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178741/warning-please-use-table-in-place-of-latex-environment